# Execute mac command from Python

Tags: python

Im trying to execute a MAC command from Python but get the following error:-

Command

```
from subprocess import call
call(["""osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Hello World" ' """])
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/premanandlakshmanan/Documents/psilon/quantopian/mac_popup.py", line 2, in <module>
    call(["""osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Hello World" ' """])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: You need to double check your sys.path to make sure it includes `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call), with `shell=False` (the default) takes a list of arguments.

Try:

```py
import subprocess

args = []
args.append('osascript')
args.append('-e')
args.append('tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Hello World"')
subprocess.call(args)
```

You are trying to execute a file called `osascript -e 'tell ap...`, which doesn't exist.

You want to execute `osascript`, with some arguments.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call), `subprocess.call()` takes a list of arguments. You need to break up your command into its individual parts.

```
from subprocess import call

args = ['osascript',
        '-e',
        'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Hello World"'
       ]
call(args)
```